# Electricity, Voltage, Potential Energy

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage, batteries

i wanted ask something about electricity:
Suppose we have a circuit:a battery and wires connected to two poles.
Also suppose wires have no resistance.
Well:When electron goes from negative to positve pole,does its potential energy change (because $U=\frac{kq_1.q_2}{r}$, so change because of distance?).
I ask that for that:If we connect a light bulb,and our battery is $9v$ (and wires without resistance) how we know that each Coulomb gives $9 joules$ to bulb (based on $v=\frac{W}{q}$) since the energy of Coulomb changes because of resistance (of bulb) but also because of distance with the other pole.So is that the true amount of energy that coulomb gives to bulb?

Answer (score 0):

The work done on the electron by the electric field between the negative and positive poles equals the negative of its change in potential energy,

$W = -\Delta U = e\Delta V$

If the electrons didn't collide with ions in the filament of the bulb, then indeed the total work done by the electric field would result as kinetic energy of the electrons (work-energy theorem!).

However, inevitably, there end up being quite a few (!) collisions between the electrons and the ions in resistive elements, and this kinetic energy is transferred to the kinetic energy of ions in the resistive elements, resulting in heating.

In circuit theory, the assumption is that there is no change in kinetic energy of the charge carriers - so essentially, all of the energy gained from the electric field is dissipated in the load! You might perhaps rationalise this by considering the constant drift velocity of electrons in a loop with constant current.

Comment: Energy  can stored in electric fields of capacitors and magnetic fields of inductors as well as dissipated in resistors

Comment: @BobD You're right, I didn't consider this in my answer! However the logic remains the same, it's just our conservation of energy looks a little different.